# Free font for block-serif Hebrew?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-recommendation

I’m developing a reference web site, to help English speakers learn the Hebrew alphabet. I’ve used character escapes for all the Hebrew letters, but they render in the [*block sans-serif*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_alphabet#Stylistic_variants) style.

I wish the Hebrew letters to render in *block serif* style, and am asking if there is a free font I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/language/hebrew) is Font Squrrel’s selection of (free) fonts supporting Hebrew. I am no expert on the distinction you want to achieve, but to me it looks like the serif fonts (Tinos and Cardo) fulfil your criteria. I haven’t looked at the sans-serif fonts.

Comment: Thanks. The distinction is the default font for ASP.NET MVC pages shows Hebrew as sans-serif, and as I am trying to learn Biblical Hebrew, without serifs on the screen, it is very hard to discern glyphs with serifs on another screen.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Fonts](http://[Here](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Serif,Handwriting&subset=hebrew)%20are%20some%20google%20fonts%20too...) have some typefaces like the ones you require too.